# 'Program.CalculateTax(double)':not all code paths return a value'

Tags: c#

I' ve  got error on this code. Its said "Not all code paths return Value"
Please hel me fix this. Thanks

```
public static double subtotal;

public static void Main(String[] args)
{
  subtotal = 15.00;
  Console.WriteLine($"Subtotal : {subtotal}");

  double total = subtotal + CalculateTax(7);
  Console.WriteLine($"Total : {total}");
}

public static double CalculateTax(double taxRate)
{
  double tax = subtotal * taxRate;
  Console.WriteLine($"Tax: {tax}");
}
```

Comment: Add `return tax;` to the end of your method

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
public static double CalculateTax(double taxRate)
{
    double tax = subtotal * taxRate;
    Console.WriteLine($"Tax: {tax}");
    return tax;
}
```